# How to connect on-premise server to Azure container registry

Tags: azure, containers, webhooks, azure-container-registry

My goal is to pull the image from Azure container registry to my on-premise server but I need to provide a webhook. How can I create a webhook on-premise server and do I need a middleware to connect to the Azure container registry? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this link for the procedure to pull the image from Azure container registry to on-premises server: - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/journey-of-an-app-how-to-push-a-container-image-from-on-premises/ba-p/1602721 ; Also, please check the below link for the process of registering Windows Admin Center on your on-premises server: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/register-windows-admin-center

Comment: @JBA did you ever get this set up? I'm curently research the same thing

Comment: @Ted I already finished this project. I used Azure Agent Pipeline to do this instead of webhook.

Comment: Thanks @JBA I'm glad to hear you managed to achieve this. Has running your own Azure Agent worked well? Have you found any problems with updating your on-premise server this way? Any advice or links you could offer on the subject would be much appreciated.